# Return an array composed of the string representation of the numbers from 1 to n, In C#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

This is the rest of the Question.
Return an array composed of the string representation of the  numbers from 1 to n.But there is a twist!! For Multiples of 3 , return the string "Darude" instand of the number, For Multiple of 5 return the string "Sandstorm"; and for multiple of both 3 and 5 ,return the string "Darude StandStorm"

This is my code

```
static string [] stringarray(int n)
 {
 string [] results= { } ;
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
{
  if (i % 3 == 0) results = new[] { "Deude" };`enter code here`
  if (i % 5 == 0) results = new[] { "Sandstome" }; 
  if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 5 == 0) results = new[] { "Darude Sandstome" }; 
    else Console.WriteLine(i);
 } 
 return results; 
}
```

---

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't give the results that I want.

Comment: `enter code here` what doing here?

Comment: @Den let rewite the question a gain,

Comment: This sounds like a version of fizzbuzz. There is an [enterprise C# version](https://github.com/jongeorge1/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition-CSharp) that might help (or not)

Comment: For a more constructive comment: When posting questions it is very useful to include the expected result, and the actual result. "Not the result I want" is not very helpful. I would also suggest that you step thru the code and inspect the variables and see if they have the state you would expect them to have.

Comment: So what will be the result you want for a number that applies in the three conditions for example the 15? Because i think your problem is that you dont structure if else properly.

Comment: The Expected results should be 1 ,2, Darude,4, Sandstorm,Darude,7,8,Darude,Sandstorm,11,Darude,12,14,Darude Sandstorm

Comment: First you are reseting result to a new array on each step, this not what you want. Also you should check first if your number is a multiple of both 3 and 5

Comment: @yanyankelevich I See what you mean, how do I declare the array so that will not reset the array

Comment: Should the method have the number checks injected? So could you inject a dictionary of the mappings such as 3 maps to "Darude", 5 to "Sandstorm" rather than having those hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. You are creating instance of array in loop so it clear the value.

```
public static string[] stringarray(int n)
        {
            string[] results = new string[n];
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    results[i - 1] = "Darude Sandstome";
                }
                else if (i % 3 == 0)
                {
                    results[i - 1] = "Deude";
                }
                else if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    results[i - 1] = "Sandstome";
                }
                else
                {
                    results[i - 1] = i.ToString();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Read the value as Below

```
string[] strResult = stringarray(16);
foreach (var item in strResult)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly better option :

```
    public static string[] stringarray(int n)
    {
        bool isMultipleOf3 =  i % 3 == 0;
        bool isMultipleOf5 = i % 5 == 0;
        string[] results = new string[n];
        
        for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        {
            if ( isMultipleOf3 && isMultipleOf5 ) 
            {
                 results[i - 1] = "Darude Sandstome";
                 continue;
            }
            
            if (isMultipleOf3 )
            {
                 results[i - 1] = "Deude";
                 continue;
             }
             if ( isMultipleOf5 ) 
             {
                 results[i - 1] = "Sandstome";
                 continue;
             }
             
             results[i - 1] = i.ToString(); //Console.WriteLine(i);
         }
         return results;
     }
```

It is better because you only compute i%3 and i%5 once. And, it is clearer what you are testing since the bool variables avec clear names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be solved this way :

```
private static string[] StringArrays(int arrayLength) =>
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, arrayLength)
        .Select(
            ComputeDarudeOrSandstormOrBoth
        )    
        .ToArray();

private static string ComputeDarudeOrSandstormOrBoth(int value)
{
    bool isDividableBy3 = value % 3 == 0;
    bool isDividableBy5 = value % 3 == 0;
    return
        isDividableBy3 && isDividableBy5
        ?
            "Darude Sandstorm"
        :
            isDividableBy3
            ?
                "Darude"
            :
                isDividableBy5
                ?
                    "Sandstorm"
                :
                    value.ToString();
}
```